# iOS 13.0 Touch begin delayed increased compare to ios 12

Tags: ios, swift, touch, gesture, ios13

In my project I have tap gesture with following setup

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewTapped(gesture:)))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

And  also has  Touch method like  `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`

I have setup touch gesture with `tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true` to work both gesture as well as Touch delegate methods

It is working fine till iOS12, But in iOS13 Touch delay has been increased so user must drag his finger and wait until drawing starts because touch method called delayed

Please refer below image  , Sometime gesture lost , Delayed on starting of drawing.

If I remove `delaysTouchesBegan` it is smooth again.

Can anyone can help me to solve this ?

[image]

**SAMPLE PROJECT**

To quick test this stuff download raywenderlich project  https://www.raywenderlich.com/5895-uikit-drawing-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app

Add Following code in `ViewController.swlft`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(gesture:)))
    tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

  }

  @objc func viewTapped(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("View Tapped")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was iOS 13.0 bug

After update to the iOS 13.1 Will fix this issue automatically

Hopefully helpful to someone :)